# DataRow not collected by GC

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, datatable

I have a problem in my application leaking some memory. this becomes a real issue when running for long hours.
I basically have the following class:

```
public class FeaturesDataSource{
     // Table used only for schema hosting
     DataTable selectedFeaturesDataTable;
     IDictionary<uint, MyFeatureType > _selectedFeaturesCache = 
          new Dictionary<uint, MyFeatureType>();
     // Create table according to a defined schema...

     // Adds or replaces an existing feature
     public void AddFeature(int featureID, MyFeatureType featureValue) {
           DataRow row = selectedFeaturesDataTable.NewRow();
           row["ID"] = featureID;
           row["Content"] = featureValue;
           if (_selectedFeaturesCache.ContainsKey(featureID) {
               _selectedFeaturesCache.Remove(featureID);
           }
           _selectedFeaturesCache.Add(featureID, row);
     }
}
```

As you can see from this method, calling `AddFeature` creates a new data row as per the table's schema and replaces any existing data row having the same ID. 
My application creates objects of type `MyFeatureType` at a rate of 1 object/second and calls the `AddFeature` with the same ID everytime:

```
// This data source gets updated in the following way
public void MethodCalledEverySecond(MyFeatureType featureValue){
     // This data source contains only one object of type MyFeatureValue, 
     // replace the existing one by specifying a constant ID
     myFeatureDataSource.AddFeature(1, featureValue);  
}
```

this should always replace the existing data row with the new one. 
At runtime, VS shows the `_selectedFeaturesCache` dictionary count always equal to 1, this expected but a `!dumpHeap -stat` shows an increasing number of objects of type `MyFeatureType` in memory where it is supposed to be always  equal to 1.
Am I doing anything wrong here? Does the `selectedFeaturesDataTable.NewRow()` keep a reference to old data rows being replaced blocking the GC from collecting them?

Comment: Why should it not have many MyFeatureType object? You probably create them before you call AddFeature.

Comment: Yes, I do create them to replace the existing ones , that is a client requirement :)

Comment: Have you checked if the objects are rooted and if so by what? !gcroot {id}

Comment: Yes, looking to their root they seem to hang on the System.DataTable class :(

Comment: Is databinding ever involved? events can be a pain for rooting things subtly... also, though, it is not inconceivable that that it simply hasn't had to do a full collect yet... GC is non-deterministic

Comment: No, no data binding involved. I left the application running for a long time so the GC has probably kicked in at some point (I hope :p )

Comment: Being pragmatic - could you not just switch to a POCO that is unrelated to the table?

Comment: I wish I could :( I am working with a framework that is based on DataRow objects and there is no other way I can create a data row without going through a DataTable.

Comment: Why don't you try to call selectedFeaturesDataTable.Clear before you add a  new Row?

Comment: Is `MyFeatureType` perhaps a struct? Sounds like boxing of copies.

Comment: @leppie +1 for the boxing stuff. Yes there is some boxing going on but I expect that boxed values are GCed along with data row when it is no longer needed

Comment: I cannot clear the table as I it contains other objects with different IDs than the one I want to replace

Comment: What does MyFeatureType inherit from ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation for the NewRow method [here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx)

> When you use NewRow to create new rows, the rows must be added to or deleted from the data table before you call Clear

Which would seem to imply that there is a reference to the DataTable from where thew row was created.

I think you will need to call Delete and then AcceptChanges on the row to detach it from the table.

Comment: Thanks for this I will give it a try tomorrow and will keep you posted :)